# Arrow functions vs Fat arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I've found on the internet about both names, **arrow functions** and **fat arrow functions** but no information about what is different between them.

Are there any differences?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Such a question requires a bit of explanation...

### ECMAScript 5

In ES5 specification, there were no **arrow functions** at all. It was then common to use traditional function expressions like so:

```
// Example n°1
var myFunction = function () {
  return 'Hello!';
};

// Example n°2
var obj = {
  myFunction: function () {
    return 'Hello!';
  }
};

// Example n°3
var arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
arr.map(function (item) {
  return 'Hello, ' + item + '!';
};
```

### CoffeeScript

When CoffeeScript was introduced by Jeremy Ashkenas, it brought a new terminology, especially **thin arrow functions** (`->`) and **fat arrow functions** (`=>`).

On the one hand, the *thin arrow function* is a CoffeeScript equivalent of the ES5 (anonymous) function expression. In CoffeeScript, we could write the previous examples like so:

```
# Example n°1
myFunction = -> 'Hello!'

# Example n°2
obj =
  myFunction: -> 'Hello!'

# Example n°3
arr = ['foo', 'bar']
arr.map((item) -> "Hello, #{item}!")
```

On the other hand, the *fat arrow function* is a nice utility provided by CoffeeScript which has no equivalent syntax in ES5. Its aim is to play more easily with lexical scoping, especially when you want to keep the outer **this** in a callback. Let's take a universal example with CoffeeScript and the legendary jQuery callback. Suppose we are in the global scope:

```
// Here "this" is "window"
console.log(this);

$(document).ready(function () {
  // Here "this" is "document"
  console.log(this);
});
```

If we want to manipulate the outer "this" in the callback, here is the ES5 code:

```
var that = this;

$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log(that);
});
```

With CoffeeScript, it is possible to use a *fat arrow function* instead:

```
// "this" is "window"!
$(document).ready => console.log this
```

Of course, it would not work with a *thin arrow function*:

```
// "this" is "document"
$(document).ready -> console.log this
```

### ECMAScript 6 (2015)

ES2015 specification introduced **arrow functions**. They are an alternative to *fat arrow functions* in CoffeeScript. But since there are no *thin arrow functions* in ES6, there is no reason to talk about fat arrow functions when you do not use CoffeeScript. In ES6, you would do this:

```
// Here "this" is "window"
$(document).ready(() => console.log(this));
```

Now if you want to preserve the normal behavior of lexical scoping, just use the ES5 syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Here "this" is "document"
  console.log(this);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

> Are there any differences?

**No.**

Except that the term "fat arrow function" is deprecated and obsolete.

This answer does not apply to CoffeeScript, in case anybody is still using that.

Answer (score 2):

In CoffeeScript fat arrow functions pass in the encapsulating scope whilst normal arrow don't.

Comment: _"pass in the encapsulating scope"_ What do you mean by that?

Comment: Take a look at Badacadabra answer for an example of what I mean.

Comment: He talks about `this`. _"pass in"_  makes no sense in combination with scope.