# How to acces to parent of "this" on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, this

I have a problem programming object-oriented in Javascript. I have the following:

```
class Foo{
    constructor(){...}
    ...
    a_needed_method(){...}
    ...
    a_method(){
        ...
        jsObject.on("click",function(params){
            this.a_needed_method();
        });
    }  
}
```

The problem is, if I call the `a_needed_method` method using `this` there, then `this` is referencing the anonymous function that controls the `onclick` event. How I can call `a_needed_method()` from this anonymous function?

Comment: That depends. Is the event handler using jQuery? How is `a_method` called *(`this` depends on execution context)* ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### ES6

You can use an **arrow function** to preserve the **lexical this**:

```
jsObject.on("click", params => {
  this.a_needed_method();
});
```

### ES5

You can use the good old `that = this`:

```
var that = this;
jsObject.on("click", function (params) {
  that.a_needed_method();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've used the updated version: __arrow function__, and works fine. I don't know this exists, because I'm just a beginner, so... Could you explain me what is an __arrow function__ and when I should use it? Thank you so much again!

Comment: You're welcome! :) If you want to learn more about **arrow functions**, I recommend you to read my in-depth answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588722/arrow-functions-vs-fat-arrow-functions/43593587#43593587

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor you can say:

```
constructor(){
  this.a_needed_method = this.a_needed_method.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the issue because inside the anonymous function, `this.a_needed_method` will still be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `bind`:

```
    jsObject.on("click",function(params){
        this.a_needed_method();
    }.bind(this));
```

```js
let jsObject = $(this);

class Foo {
  constructor() {

  }

  a_needed_method() {
    console.log('That works !');
  }

  a_method() {
    jsObject.on("click", function(params) {
      this.a_needed_method();
    }.bind(this));
  }
}

let x = new Foo();
x.a_method();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click anywhere
```

or `arrow` function from `es6`:

```
    jsObject.on("click",(params) => {
        this.a_needed_method();
    });
```

```js
let jsObject = $(this);

class Foo {
  constructor() {

  }

  a_needed_method() {
    console.log('That works !');
  }

  a_method() {
    jsObject.on("click", (params) => {
      this.a_needed_method();
    });
  }
}

let x = new Foo();
x.a_method();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click anywhere
```

Comment: You need to bind `this` to the function passed as a parameter to `on` not to the `on` function's return value.

Comment: @Titus thanks for remind me about that, I have updated with a twice bind. :)

Comment: Why do you think the last bind is needed at all? In fact, the last one is the deprecated jQuery `.bind()` method, not the `Function.prototype.bind`, and passing `this` to it wouldn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `this` is the class inside `a_method`, and that it's called with that execution context, and assuming the event handler is using jQuery, you could simply use [`event.data`](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/) to pass anything you'd like to the event handlers callback, that's what `event.data` was meant to do

```
a_method(){
    ...
    jsObject.on("click", {klass : this}, function(params){
        params.data.klass.a_needed_method();
    });
}
```

```js
let jsObject = $(this);

class Foo{
    constructor(){
    
    }

    a_needed_method(){
      console.log('That works !');
    }

    a_method(){
        jsObject.on("click", {klass : this}, function(params){
            params.data.klass.a_needed_method();
        });
    }  
}

let x = new Foo();
x.a_method();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click anywhere
```