# Get reference of a function located in the same object

Tags: javascript, scope

I cannot figure out why the following does not work:

```
var foo = { f1: () => 5, f2: this.f1() }
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: this.f1 is not a function

It seems that `this` refers to the global scope instead of `foo`. Everything works fine with the following:

```
var foo = { f1: () => 5, f2() { return this.f1 } }
```

Is there a way to refer to `f1` without wrapping it in a new function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope where you're executing the assignment is global scope, so `this` is not `foo`. One might think that this would then fix it:

```
var foo = { f1: () => 5, f2: foo.f1() }
```

but it doesn't - because at the time when the literal is constructing the object, the assignment hasn't happened, and `foo` is still `undefined`.

You need to take timing into account, and write one of the following:

```
var foo = { f1: () => 5 }
foo.f2 = foo.f1
```

or

```
var f = () => 5
var foo = { f1: f, f2: f }
```

Of course, if you want to simply resolve to `f1` at runtime, and don't want to explicitly invoke a function with parentheses, you can still sneak in a function as a getter:

```
var foo = { f1: () => 5, get f2() { return foo.f1 } }
foo.f2
# => [Function: f1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is probably helpful:

[How does the "this" keyword in Javascript act within an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441307/how-does-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-act-within-an-object-literal)

This answer also has useful comments on the difference between arrow and regular functions, particularly how `this` is affected in each:

[Arrow functions vs Fat arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588722/arrow-functions-vs-fat-arrow-functions/43593587)

```js
var testOne = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: () => console.log(this.a)
}

var testTwo = {}

testTwo.a = 'hello'
testTwo.b = function() {console.log(this.a)}

console.log(testOne.a)
testOne.b()

console.log(testTwo.a)
testTwo.b()
```