# jQuery input value undefined or white text

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jquery-events

This question has probably been asked and answerd a thousand times before, but I don't know if it's because of SEO, I've not found a suitable solution. I either get undefined or blank text in Chrome.

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('input', (a, b) => {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

This keeps returning undefined in the console I've also tried:

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('input', (a, b) => {
       console.log(b);
    });

$('input[type="text"]').on('input', (a, b) => {
       console.log($(this).val());
    });

$('input[type="text"]').on('input', (a, b) => {
       console.log(a.value);
    });

$('input[type="text"]').on('input', (a, b) => {
       console.log(b.value);
    });
```

Any idea's would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `this` keyword will not work us you expect since you're using es6 arrow function format what will change the context, use `e.target` instead of it.

Take a look at [What does “this” refer to in arrow functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371982/what-does-this-refer-to-in-arrow-functions-in-es6)

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on('input', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test">
```

Comment: Wow that solved it! I didn't know the fat arrow changed the way returning values work!

Comment: Yes take a look to [Arrow functions vs Fat arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588722/arrow-functions-vs-fat-arrow-functions/43593587)

Comment: 'e.target.value.test' why is this than not possible?

Comment: The values attribute has no `test` property, what you want to get exactly?

Comment: I want to test a RegExp on the input value

Comment: It should be `new RegExp("your_regex").test(e.target.value);`

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using arrow function the scope of which is different from normal function.

Normally you can replace arrow function with conventional function expression & use `$(this)` or use the target object from event handler to get the value of the input

```js
$('input[type="text"]').on('input', function(a, b) {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$('input[type="text"]').on('input', (a, b) => {
  console.log(a.target.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
```

Comment: This is identical to the other answer :|

Comment: @MoshFeu take a better look

Comment: You added now the regular `function` method.. Nice.

Comment: That was added even before your first comment. Please validate it from revision history

Comment: When you right, you right :)